# How to set a scroll bar to start from the top in Android?

Tags: android, listview, layout, scroll

I have this layout xml file for an activity which uses a listview.
It works fine except it always starts from the top of the listview. Not from the top of the layout. I tested

```
listView.setSelection(0);
```

It didn't work for me.
How can I display the screen from the top?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/topLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/darkbackground"
>

<include layout="@layout/subtitle_bar" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/rankHistory"
android:text="@string/rankHistory"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="20px"
android:textSize="24sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ffffffff"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
></TextView>

<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_marginTop="15px"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="500px"
android:dividerHeight="15px"
android:divider="@color/darkbackground"
>
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Here you can download sample project http://www.hrupin.com/2011/10/14/how-to-scroll-listview-to-top-or-other-position

Hope, it help you!

Comment: Give me some time. I will make test project and try to fix this. It is interesting for me too :)

Comment: Thank you for your trouble ihrupin, but still it didn't work for me..
gave me this error: "The method smoothScrollToPosition(int) is undefined for the type ListView"

Comment: public void smoothScrollToPosition (int position)
Since: API Level 8
@Kou. What version Android API your application use? This methid (smoothScrollToPosition (int) ) available in Android since API 8 or Android 2.2. Thy to download my sample project

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put a ListView in a ScrollView. Put the items above the ListView in a separate xml file and then add them as a header to the ListView by using `listView.addHeaderView(view);`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion Maria Neumayer. I'm gonna try it later.

Comment: Thanks! it worked! if I scroll it the view also comes with it, but I guess there's no alternative for version 1.6. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh so you don't want the rest of the screen to scroll? The scrollbar is linked to the ListView. Therefore it will only be shown where the ListView starts, which makes sense - I guess it's confusing if the scrollbar starts on top of the screen and the whole screen is not scrolling.
So if you put your layout not in a ScrollView, but in a LinearLayout it should display everything correctly, but the scrollbar will start with the ListView.